# How to loop through array in C# 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, c#-4.0, foreach

What is the easiest way to loop through an array in `C# 4.0` ?

eg.

```
foreach (var msg in MyObject.MyArray)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": " + msg.code);
}
```

Is there a more 'modern' way in `C# 4.0` to do the above?

Comment: Just to be super technical - do you want it restricted to C#, or are functions from the .Net framework okay to use?

Comment: I would like to know about C# specific syntax.

Answer (score 2):

A loop is a loop. If you want to loop through an array, you probably won't find anything better than, well, a loop. Most of the other answers here create an unnecessary List just to use the syntactic sugar of the ForEach method, but it's still just a loop.

If you want a more modern frame of mind, don't ask "How can I loop over the array", but instead try to think what you're looping *for*. If, for example, you're constructing an output string from the members of the array, you could use `string.Join`, as @Selman22 mentions in the comments:

```
var output = string.Join(", ", MyObject.MyArray.Select(item => item.code);
```

or use the LINQ method `Aggregate` for more complicated aggregations, like aggregating the strings in reverse order:

```
MyObject.MyArray.Aggregate((output, nextItem) => nextItem.code + output);
```

If you're constructing new items based on that array values, use `Select`:

```
var statuses = MyObject.MyArray.Select(item => new StatusMessage(item.code));
```

And so forth. Don't try to reinvent the loop. Try to see where you don't actually need an explicit loop.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the obvious while everyone else dived into LINQ.

Comment: also, instead of `Aggregate`, `string.Join` can be used

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this using [Array.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string[] bar = {"1", "2", "3"};
Array.ForEach(bar, foo => Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": " + foo));
```

So for your example it would be

```
Array.ForEach(MyObject.MyArray, msg => Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": " + msg.code));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its more about readability than being modern. You can use [`List.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but it is arguable whether this adds value:

```
MyObject.MyArray
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(msg => Debug.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", DateTime.Now, msg.code));
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are looking to stick strictly to C# 4.0, then the answer is no**, there is no more elegant way than what you are currently doing. The C# 4.0 spec seems to have gone AWOL (it's morphed into the [C# 5.0 reference](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029)) but let me refer you to the closest thing I can find which is the [C# reference for VS2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32dbftby%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (which pretty much coincides with 4.0).

However as a few other answers have pointed out there are some nice selection and iteration constructs built into LINQ, while they might be overkill for a simple loop they can be very nice for isolating out partial lists or for processing larger lists (especially when used in conjunction with PLINQ).

Answer (score -1):

Using [LINQ](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b):

```
MyObject.MyArray.Select(x => String.Format("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now,x.code)).ToList().ForEach(Debug.WriteLine)
```

Comment: How can this be modified to include the `DateTime.Now` string?

Answer (score -1):

There are few ways, I listed those which are most relevant with some briefing:

```
var items = new[] {"ItemA", "ItemB", "ItemC", "ItemD", "ItemE"};

//option 1 - most intuative.
foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
    //other instructions of the iteration..
}

//option 2 - full control over the iterator.
for (var index = 0; index < items.Length; index++)
{
    var item = items[index];
    Console.WriteLine(item);
    //other instructions of the iteration..
}

//option 3a - shortest, modern.. but also less efficient due to the casting.
items.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

//option 3b - same as 3a but can have more instructions inside..
items.ToList().ForEach(item =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
    //other instructions of the iteration..
});
```